# Preprocessor "invalid integer constant expression" comparing int to double

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Somewhere in my code, I have preprocessor definition

```
#define ZOOM_FACTOR 1
```

In another place I have

```
#ifdef ZOOM_FACTOR
#if (ZOOM_FACTOR == 1)
#define FONT_SIZE 8
#else
#define FONT_SIZE 12
#endif
#else
#define FONT_SIZE 8
#endif
```

The problem is when I change `ZOOM_FACTOR` value to `floating point` value, for example `1.5`, I'm getting compile error `C1017: invalid integer constant expression`.

Does anyone know why am I getting this error and is there any way to make a comparison between `integer` and `floating point number` within preprocessor directive?

Comment: Try to use "greater", "greater or equal", "lower" or "lower or equal" comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because the language does not permit it.

As per the C++ standard, [**`[cpp.cond]/1`**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.cond#1):

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integral constant expression.

Instead of defining `ZOOM_FACTOR` as floating point value `1.5`, why not define it as a multiple of such value. For example, multiply with a constant such as `2` and then make your comparisons.